# How can I remove days from another month using UI-Calendar from UI-AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using ui-calendar to build a dynamic calendar for my app. How can I remove days from another months?

For example:
The calendar shows April. But I don't want to show days from March and May.

Obs:
I can put a visibility class to the elements like that

```
$(".fc-other-month").css({ "visibility" : "hidden" });
```

But I don't know if it's the correct for to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
fixedWeekCount: false
```

You can see in the documentation (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/fixedWeekCount/)